# Выполнить Replace по словарю через LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Допустим, есть Dictionary и текст.

Нужно по словарю заменить 1 буквы на другие.

Стандартное решение- это пройтись циклом по словарю и вызвать Replace N-раз.

А можно ли это изобразить в виде LINQ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если порядок замен не важен, то например так:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>() { ["Hello"] = "Goodbye", ["world"] = "America" };
var text = "Hello world";
var result = dict.Aggregate(text, (s, kvp) => s.Replace(kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
Console.WriteLine(result); // Goodbye America
```

Comment: Разве в исходном вопросе речь о string? Вижу там про char упоминание.

Comment: @AK: Ну, `Dictionary<char, char>`, от этого код не меняется.