# Замена символов C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Каким образом можно заменить в тексте буквы на соответственные эмодзи  к примеру "a" на "смайл буквы а" и так со всем английским алфавитом, ведь если использовать input.Replace с каждой буквой, заменяются буквы во всем конечном тексте?
Пример [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам код:

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //по клику происходит замена
    {
        string input = inputText.Text; 
        input = input.Replace("a", " :regional_indicator_a: ");
        input = input.Replace("b", " :regional_indicator_b: ");
        input = input.Replace("c", " :regional_indicator_с: ");
        outputText.Text = input;
    }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выполнить Replace по словарю через LINQ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797910/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-replace-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8e-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-linq)

Comment: @AK чет не похоже на дубликат, попробуйте тот код для этой задачи

Comment: приведите пример строки: что "на входе", чего хотим "на выходе"; если вы хотите заменить не все буквы -- по какому критерию выделяете желаемые под замену??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например, так

```
public class EmoReplacer
{
    private Dictionary<char, string> _emo = new Dictionary<char, string>
    {
        {'a', ":regional_indicator_a:"},
        {'b', ":regional_indicator_b:"},
        {'c', ":regional_indicator_c:"},
    };

    public string Replace(string input)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(var c in input)
        {
            if (_emo.ContainsKey(c))
                sb.Append(_emo[c]);
            else sb.Append(c);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Как использовать

```
var replacer = new EmoReplacer();
var text = "a b c d e f";
Console.WriteLine(replacer.Replace(text));
```

Вывод

```
:regional_indicator_a: :regional_indicator_b: :regional_indicator_c: d e f
```

Answer (score 1):

Через регулярки получится даже заменять по несколько символов:

```
string input = "a b c. qq";
input = Regex.Replace(input, "(a|b|c|qq)", m =>
{
    switch (m.Value)
    {
        case "a": return ":regional_indicator_a:";
        case "b": return ":regional_indicator_b:";
        case "c": return ":regional_indicator_c:";
        case "qq": return ":qq:";
        default:
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
});
Console.WriteLine(input);
```

Если нужно заменить только буквы, тогда можно еще проще:

```
string input = "a b c x y w";
input = Regex.Replace(input, @"(\w)", m => $":regional_indicator_{m.Value}:");
Console.WriteLine(input);
```

Comment: Забавно.. медленней цикла, но гораздо удобней. Ловите плюсик :)