# Изменить под регулярные выражения

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Как заменить кучу Replace на регулярные выражения ?

```
text = text.Replace("[", " ( ").Replace("]", " ) ").Replace("<", " < ").Replace(">", " > ")
                    .Replace("(", " ( ").Replace(")", " ) ").Replace(",", "").Replace(".", "").Replace("++", " ++")
                    .Replace("--", " --").Replace(";", "").Replace("'", "").Replace("\t", "").Replace("\"", "");
```

Есть исходный текст кода. Нужно убрать все скобки, двойные пробелы, ;, точки, слешы и одинарные и двойные кавычки.

Comment: Одной регуляркой тут не обойтись

Comment: Вообще какие-то странные замены, а если вокруг скобки уже есть пробелы, то все равно их надо добавить? Если в тексте будет квадратная скобка, она будет заменена на круглую с пробелами, а потом круглая будет опять заменена на круглую с еще пробелами... Полагаю, лучше бы вам озвучить свою фактическую задачу.

Comment: Пройтись циклом по исходной строке и сформировать новую в `StringBuilder`.

Comment: А если использовать словарь для изменений? Скажем, как [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/797913/220553)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать следующий код, где с помощью регулярного выражения можно за один проход заменить большинство символов, а после нужно будет только добавить парочку методов `Replace` для замены квадратных скобок на круглые:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var text = "[(Hello) <world>;.,]++--\t\"'";
        var result = Regex.Replace(text, @"([][()<>])|(\+\+|--)|[""'\t;.,]", m =>
            m.Groups[1].Success ? $" {m.Groups[1].Value} " : 
            m.Groups[2].Success ? $" {m.Groups[2].Value}" : "")
            .Replace("[", "(").Replace("]", ")");
        Console.WriteLine(result); 
    }
}
```

См. [демо C#](https://ideone.com/j9foys).

Строка `[(Hello) <world>;.,]++--\t"` заменится  `(  ( Hello )   < world >  )  ++ --`.

Регулярка работает следующим образом:

- `([][()<>])` - захватывающая группа №1: находит скобки (их заключаем в пробелы)
- `|` - или
- `(\+\+|--)` - захватывающая группа №2: либо `++`, либо `--)` (перед ними добавляем пробел)
- `|` - или
- `[""'\t;.,]` - двойная или одиночная кавычка, знак табуляции, точка, точка с запятой или запятая (удаляются).