# Replace отложенная инициализация

Tags: c#, строки, replace

Есть исходная строка, слова в которой необходимо заменять на результаты выполнения методов. Соответственно, если заменять нечего, то и метод выполнять не нужно.

Сейчас имею такой код:

```
if (str.Contains("${Time}")) str = str.Replace("${Time}", qq());
if (str.Contains("${Sec}")) str = str.Replace("${Sec}", ww());
if (str.Contains("${Min}")) str = str.Replace("${Min}", ee());
```

Но выглядит он неуклюже, особенно, когда таких замен 50.
Каким образом можно сократить запись?

Мне будет достаточно того, что бы не нужно было писать "${Time}" дважды. И повторю, что если заменять нечего, то и метод выполнять не нужно.

Comment: как вариант можно переписать используя тернарный оператор, например `str.Contains("${Time}") ? str = str.Replace("${Time}", qq()):/*здесь что должно быть сделано в случае  не выполнения условия*/`, но было 100 строк, станет 50. мне кажется оптимизировать в этом случае не это

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выполнить Replace по словарю через LINQ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797910/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-replace-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8e-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-linq)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ если заменять нечего, то и метод выполнять не нужно.

Comment: напишите функцию, которая будет переменную принимать и заменять. Так появится одна точка входа для этой и других 50-ти проверок

Comment: @gil9red если заменять нечего, то и метод выполнять не нужно.

Comment: я не имел ввиду просто замену, добавьте туда и проверку: `public string foo(string str, string text) { if (str.Contains(text)) str = str.Replace(text, qq()); return str; }` ну и вызывать так: `foo(str, "${Time}");`. Меня только `qq()` смущает -- непонятно предназначение

Comment: @gil9red дополнил вопрос. Надеюсь, так понятнее.

Comment: @Виталий Ну так в том ответе и не будет выполняться какая либо замена, если не найдено подходящего. Переделать только на `Dictionary<int, Func<string, string>>` и все.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Автор, я это имел ввиду:

```
public class Program
{
    public static String FooReplace(String str, String oldValue, Func<string> fn)
    {
        if (str.Contains(oldValue))
        {
            str = str.Replace(oldValue, fn());
        }
        
        return str;
    }
    
    public static String ww()
    {
        return new string("World".Reverse().ToArray());
    }
    
    public static String ee()
    {
        return "123";
    }
    
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = "Hello World!";
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        Console.WriteLine();
        
        text = FooReplace(text, "!", () => "!!!");
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        
        String world = "World";
        text = FooReplace(text, "{world}", ww);
        Console.WriteLine(text);
   
        text = FooReplace(text, "Hel", ee);
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

Консоль:

```
Hello World!

Hello World!!!
Hello dlroW!!!
123lo dlroW!!!
```

---

**PS.** еще можно немного сократить код, если поместить значения и ссылки на функции в коллекцию (например в словарь), а после перебрать в цикле:

```
...
String world = "World";

var oldByNewValue = new Dictionary<string, Func<string>>
{
    {"!", () => "!!!"},
    {"{world}", ww},
    {"Hel", ee},
};

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Func<string>> kvp in oldByNewValue)
{
    text = FooReplace(text, kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
...
```

Answer (score -1):

В вашем коде Contains бессмысленный, достаточно только Replace. то есть если подстрока содержится, то она будет заменена, если не содержится, то и менять нечего, поэтому вам достаточно просто:

```
str = str
  .Replace("${Time}", qq());
  .Replace("${Sec}", ww());
  .Replace("${Min}", ee());
```

Comment: ага, только в этом случае все методы будут выполнены, даже если их результат не нужен.

Comment: Вашем случае Contains тоже выполнится если результат не нужен. По сути, Contains и Replace работают практически одинаково, только последний в случае обнаружения совпадения произведет замену и пойдет дальше, если же совпадений нет, то просто пройдет по строке точно так же как и Contains